# ClojureScript circular dependency

Tags: clojure, dependencies, circular-dependency, clojurescript

I'm struggling with a circular dependency in ClojureScript. I'm trying out this language for a month, haven't ever worked with the real thing (Clojure).

I have a client side app that uses [secretary](https://github.com/gf3/secretary) as a router. When I'm defining my routes, they're handler functions, push values to the `history-channel`, which is then consumed by the main app component that displays particular views. Thus, the values I push from my routes, contain a reference to the `view` function. This view function are [om](https://github.com/swannodette/om) components that render the given location. In these view functions, I often need to generate links, URLs to other locations in the app. These URLs are generated from the same handler functions that references them. That's how my circular dependency is born. What is an elegant way to resolve it?

```
router -> views -> router
```

-- route.cljs

```
(ns myapp.route
  (:require [secretary.core :as secretary :include-macros true :refer [defroute]]
            [myapp.views.welcome :as welcome]
            [myapp.views.some :as some]))

(defroute home "/" {}
  (put! history-chan {:token "/"
                      :view welcome/view}))

(defroute some "/some" {}
  (put! history-chan {:token "/some"
                      :view some/view}))
```

-- welcome.cljs

```
(ns myapp.views.welcome
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [sablono.core :as html :refer-macros [html]]
            [myapp.route :as route]))

(defn view [state owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (html [:div [:a {:href (route/some)}]]))))
```

Comment: move everything to one file :-)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no easy answers to circular dependencies in Clojure. Your best bet is to refactor, rewrite your code to remove the dependency in one direction.

Comment: Thanks @ErikKronberg I'd appreciate if you'd give an example on how to refactor this particular case. That would be very helpful.

Comment: I wonder if a reverse URL function (e.g. as in Django) might be a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular dependencies in Clojure have no easy or elegant solutions. Most likely you have to restructure your code. You'll have to mess around with it to find something you like. Just off the top of my head I might do something like this:

**-- route.cljs**

```
(ns myapp.route
  (:require [secretary.core :as secretary :include-macros true :refer [defroute]]
            [myapp.views.welcome :as welcome]
            [myapp.views.some :as some]))

(defroute home "/" {}
  (welcome/route))

(defroute some "/some" {}
  (put! history-chan {:token "/some"
                      :view some/view}))
```

**-- welcome.cljs**

```
(ns myapp.views.welcome
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [sablono.core :as html :refer-macros [html]]))

(declare view)

(defn route []
  (put! history-chan {:token "/"
                      :view view}))

(defn view [state owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (html [:div [:a {:href (route)}]]))))
```

That's just one possible solution.

Comment: Not bad Erik, not bad. However, the trick lies in the `defroute` macro. With `secretary` I have to call the generated named function. I can't simply call `route`, it would not give me the token, it would simply call what `secretary` calls when the location changes, ie. `put!`.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem, I don't use route/some to generate urls.

Router (history.cljs) include all views:

```
        [react.nav :as nav]
        [react.loading :as loading]
        [react.alerts :as alerts]
........
(def history (History.))

(events/listen
 history (.-NAVIGATE goog.history.EventType)
 (fn [e]
   (secretary/dispatch! (.-token e))))

(defroute "alerts" {:as params}
  (nav/switch-to "Alerts")
  (alerts/display))
```

Views doesn't require router.
Links works like this:

```
(def history (History.))
   .....
          :on-click (fn [e]
            (.preventDefault e)
            (.setToken history link))}
```

You can call setToken with any link you need: `(str "alerts/" sort-key "/" filter-str)`

HTH

Comment: Right, but I don't want to duplicate the string when calling `setToken`, I want secretary to generate it. DRY: when I change the route in `defroute`, I don't have to go through views and guess (grep) where I used that string.